# Testing for package conflicts in Prolog

Tags: linux, recursion, dependencies, prolog, package

It's a Prolog program that I want to check for dependencies between Linux packages and if there are conflicts anywhere.

```
dep(gnome1,gcc7).
confl(gcc7,gcc8).

% recursive chain dependency
depend(X,Y):- dep(X,Y).
depend(X,Y):- dep(X,Z), depend(Z,Y).

% conflict(X,Y) holds if X and Y depend
on two packages which conflict, conflict between two
packages should be a symmetric relation.

% my poor attempt
conflict(X,Y):- depend(X,A), depend(Y,B), (confl(A,B) | confl(B,A)).
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that your approach it's almost right:

```
dep(gnome1,libc7).
dep(gnome1,gcc7).

dep(gnome2,gnome1).
dep(gnome2,gcc8).

confl(gcc7,gcc8).

% recursive chain dependency
depend(X,Y):- dep(X,Y).
depend(X,Y):- dep(X,Z), depend(Z,Y).

% conflict(X,Y) holds if X and Y depend
% on two packages which conflict, conflict between two
% packages should be a symmetric relation.

conflict(X,Y) :-
    depend(X,A), depend(Y,B),
    X @< Y,  % break symmetry
    (confl(A,B) ; confl(B,A)).
```

I added a bit of (mis)configuratoin to test:

```
11 ?- conflict(X,Y).
X = gnome1,
Y = gnome2 ;
false.
```

Comment: Hmm... I get this output?- conflict(swiprolog330,Y).
Y = xmoose79 ;
Y = xmoose79 ;
Y = xmoose79 ;
false.

Comment: I should get 7 distinct results :/

Comment: please, post your data to get some additional help

Comment: Do you mean all the predicates for direct conflicts and dependencies?

Comment: I mean the minimal data required to repeat your test.